# should this be a multiple drive error in vhdl

Tags: vhdl, fpga

Consider this VHDL code:

```
process(a, b)
begin
    equal <= '0'; --default
    gt <= '0'; --default
    if a=b then
        equal <= '1';
    end if;
    if a>b then
        gt <= '1';
    end if;
end process;
```

The so called 'default' values are supposed to protect from having latches for signals `gt` and `equal`. But since this is not a clocked process shouldn't this be an error of multiple drivers for signals `gt` and `equal`?

Comment: No, this is fine because you only have one process driving the signals.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.7.2 Drivers, para 1 (in part): Every signal assignment statement in a process statement defines a set of *drivers* for certain scalar signals. There is a single driver for a given scalar signal S in a process statement, provided that there is at least one signal assignment statement in that process statement and that the longest static prefix of the target signal of that signal assignment statement denotes S or denotes a composite signal of which S is a subelement. ...

Comment: so is it valid to write something like 
a<='0'; 
a<='1' ;
in a process without clock?

Comment: With or without a clock. 10.5.2.2 Executing a simple assignment statement, para 1 (in part): The effect of execution of a simple waveform assignment statement is defined in terms of its effect upon the projected output waveforms (see 14.7.2) representing the current and future values of drivers of signals. (The rules are described in 10.5, for any one time there is only one projected output waveform (a queue), with no delay provided the current sim time. The second waveform replaces the first. To see both there needs to be an intervening wait.)

Comment: without a clock is makes sense for ease of coding when trying to avoid latches. But with a clock? Doesn't it create unnecessary circuit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a multiple drive situation because your signals are driven by one single process (unless you also drive them from another process, of course). So it is fine. What puzzles you, maybe, is when the same signal is assigned several times during the same process execution. The complete and detailed answer is far too complex for this short answer. But to make it simple, if you use only *simple* signal assignments (no `after` clause, no waveforms...), then the last assignment wins.

The reason is that each time the `gt <= <value>` instruction is executed, the `<value>` is not assigned immediately to signal `gt`. Instead it is recorded somewhere in the simulator's memory as *the value to assign to signal `gt` at the end of the current simulation step*. And at the end of the current simulation step, after all processes have been executed and are suspended on a `wait` statement (or on their sensitivity list, which is equivalent to a `wait` statement) the simulator updates signal `gt` with the recorded value.

So, if you execute, in the same simulation step:

```
gt <= '0';
...
gt <= '1';
```

the second assignment will overwrite the value recorded by the first assignment and `gt` will take value `'1'` at the end of the simulation step.

Comment: is this also safe for synthesis? so gt will actually be tight to '1'?

Comment: @user2609910 Absolutely, this is a very simple construct that all synthesizers I know will handle as expected.